# Embed angularjs app in another angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, grafana

I'm trying to embed grafana inside my angularjs app. I can do it easily with a simple iframe but my app uses jwt for authentication and I can't find a way to set a header for an iframe. I've confirmed that it works perfectly fine when I turn authentication off with the basic iframe but I need it enabled to use in production.

I've also tried using `$http` to get the grafana html(this way I can set my jwt header) but the js doesn't seem to work using this method. I assume it's related to the bootstraping since they bootstrap manually.

```
//iframe
<iframe id="grafana" layout-fill flex></iframe>

//controller
  $http.get('/grafana/dashboard').then(function(response) {
      var iframeDocument = document.getElementById('grafana').contentWindow.document
      iframeDocument.open('text/html', 'replace')
      iframeDocument.write(response.data)
      iframeDocument.close()
  })
```

Is there other way I can set a header on an iframe? I also tried just using grafana's html as a template but as I said before their bootstrapping seems to not work within another app.

Comment: It's not possible to set a header on an iframe. An iframe is retrieved only via GET: i.e. with a URL and a query string

Answer (score 0):

You cantry it this way, it should work:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "/grafana/dashboard",
    contentType: "application/json",
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("some_custom_header", "foo");},
    success: function(data){
        $("#output_iframe_id").attr('src',"data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(data))
    }
});
```